# CSS Challenge Mobile Bottom Form Design

Tags: css, mobile, menu, navigation

I'm new in this world of CSS and I want to create this form html and CSS can you helpme? (icons shapes is not important just the purple, orange and shadows parts)

[image: Bottom Navigation Mobile Bar Menu]

This is first version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-haze-2rc5f?file=/src/App.js

```css
.MuiBottomNavigation-root {
  height: 56px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.MuiTouchRipple-root {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: inherit;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.MuiTouchRipple-ripple {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.MuiTouchRipple-rippleVisible {
  opacity: 0.3;
  animation: MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-enter 550ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.MuiTouchRipple-ripplePulsate {
  animation-duration: 200ms;
}

.MuiTouchRipple-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: currentColor;
}

.MuiTouchRipple-childLeaving {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-exit 550ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.MuiTouchRipple-childPulsate {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-pulsate 2500ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 200ms infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.1;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.3;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-exit {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.92);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.MuiButtonBase-root {
  color: inherit;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.MuiButtonBase-root::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
}

.MuiButtonBase-root.Mui-disabled {
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media print {
  .MuiButtonBase-root {
    color-adjust: exact;
  }
}

.MuiBottomNavigationAction-root {
  flex: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  padding: 6px 12px 8px;
  max-width: 168px;
  min-width: 80px;
  transition: color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms, padding-top 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
}

.MuiBottomNavigationAction-root.MuiBottomNavigationAction-iconOnly {
  padding-top: 16px;
}

.MuiBottomNavigationAction-root.Mui-selected {
  color: #3f51b5;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.MuiBottomNavigationAction-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.MuiBottomNavigationAction-label {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  transition: font-size 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.MuiBottomNavigationAction-label.MuiBottomNavigationAction-iconOnly {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.MuiBottomNavigationAction-label.Mui-selected {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.MuiSvgIcon-root {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}

.MuiSvgIcon-colorPrimary {
  color: #3f51b5;
}

.MuiSvgIcon-colorSecondary {
  color: #f50057;
}

.MuiSvgIcon-colorAction {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.MuiSvgIcon-colorError {
  color: #f44336;
}

.MuiSvgIcon-colorDisabled {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeInherit {
  font-size: inherit;
}

.MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeSmall {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeLarge {
  font-size: 2.1875rem;
}

.makeStyles-root-1 {
  width: 500px;
}

.makeStyles-bottomBar-2 {
  background: #59378e !important;
}

.makeStyles-iconColors-3 {
  color: white !important;
}

.makeStyles-iconRelevant-4 {
  color: white;
  background: #cf8c5a !important;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MuiBottomNavigation-root makeStyles-bottomBar-2"><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiBottomNavigationAction-root makeStyles-iconColors-3 Mui-selected" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiBottomNavigationAction-wrapper"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z"></path>
      </svg><span class="MuiBottomNavigationAction-label Mui-selected">Home</span></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiBottomNavigationAction-root makeStyles-iconColors-3" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiBottomNavigationAction-wrapper"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M11.8 10.9c-2.27-.59-3-1.2-3-2.15 0-1.09 1.01-1.85 2.7-1.85 1.78 0 2.44.85 2.5 2.1h2.21c-.07-1.72-1.12-3.3-3.21-3.81V3h-3v2.16c-1.94.42-3.5 1.68-3.5 3.61 0 2.31 1.91 3.46 4.7 4.13 2.5.6 3 1.48 3 2.41 0 .69-.49 1.79-2.7 1.79-2.06 0-2.87-.92-2.98-2.1h-2.2c.12 2.19 1.76 3.42 3.68 3.83V21h3v-2.15c1.95-.37 3.5-1.5 3.5-3.55 0-2.84-2.43-3.81-4.7-4.4z"></path>
      </svg><span class="MuiBottomNavigationAction-label">Budget</span></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiBottomNavigationAction-root makeStyles-iconRelevant-4" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiBottomNavigationAction-wrapper"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M13 7h-2v4H7v2h4v4h2v-4h4v-2h-4V7zm-1-5C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"></path>
      </svg><span class="MuiBottomNavigationAction-label">NewCard</span></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiBottomNavigationAction-root makeStyles-iconColors-3" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiBottomNavigationAction-wrapper"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13 9.5h5v-2h-5v2zm0 7h5v-2h-5v2zm6 4.5H5c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h14c1.1 0 2 .9 2 2v14c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2zM6 11h5V6H6v5zm1-4h3v3H7V7zM6 18h5v-5H6v5zm1-4h3v3H7v-3z"></path>
      </svg><span class="MuiBottomNavigationAction-label">Wallet</span></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiBottomNavigationAction-root makeStyles-iconColors-3" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiBottomNavigationAction-wrapper"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 12c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm0 2c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v2h16v-2c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z"></path>
      </svg><span class="MuiBottomNavigationAction-label">Profile</span></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Alejandro, you really need to show a [reprex] with the work you have done sofar, otherwise you will get downvoted and your question probably closed in no time. People at SO are always willing to help, but not from scratch....

Comment: Thank you I will try then...

Comment: I create this example it's ok? https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-haze-2rc5f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You have still not provided a [mre]

Comment: I´m sorry I will try to do my best...